# Any tools to manage and apply my configuration (installed packaged and so on) from machine-to-machine?

Tags: configuration

You know, when you get brand new computer you have to install your toolchain, like vim/emacs, git/hg/..., ack, etc. Someday I've tired of doing this manually, and I've started to think how can I automate this process. Firstly there was a shell script, but bash is not as expressive as I want. Moreover, I want to keep my stuff cross-platform, independent of the things like yam/apt and so on. That's how I switched to puppet (and yes, I know about chef and fabric). But this tools are network oriented and I have a sense that my use is not idiomatic.

I have heard about [FAI](http://fai-project.org/), but maybe there is much more pleasant tools, oriented for **local** use (on a par with puppet) that could help me to keep my config from machine-to-machine?

Answer (score 2):

Nope, I'd say that Puppet (or it's equivalent, chef) is the tool you want.  While you *can* use those tools over a network, and that's the most common use case, they also can be used standalone, to apply a manifest (or cookbook) entirely locally, and I've used that mode to great effect for exactly the purpose you describe.

Comment: I know that I can apply puppet recipes localy (this is how I currently use it), but I thought that there could be a product that is not *client-server* oriented by nature.

Comment: Puppet is not client-server oriented by nature.